# Need to scroll Bootstrap modal with large height with the background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal which has height more than the browser screen height. The requirement is that there should not be any vertical scroll bar for the modal exclusively. There can be one for the page. Another one is that the modal should move along with the background.

Now to achieve this and going through lot of similar questions I made the below changes to the modal class:

```
.modal{
 position: from 'fixed' to 'absolute';
 overflow-y: from 'auto' to 'hidden'
}
```

Although this solves my problems as no scroll bar is coming and the modal moves along with the background, the problem is that in smaller screens or screens having lesser resolution the content is getting lost/hidden. Adjusting the width is not a solution as I can never be sure what the resolution will be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused at what you are asking - you do not want scroll bars, but your content is overflowing on certain device sizes (with smaller vertical height than your development machine). I don't think there is a solution to this, your content is greater than the space available - either have less content or allow scrolling?

Comment: What do you mean by "the modal should move along with the background", if the modal has more height then the view, and it moves with page, how will the user be able to see the rest of the model? only then he finished scrolling?

Comment: `Adjusting the width is not a solution as I can never be sure what the resolution will be.` Would the use of media queries overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

May be your solution is below. just put these css to your stylesheet.

```
    .modal-open{
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .modal-open .modal{
        overflow-y: initial;
    }
    .modal{
        position: absolute;
        bottom:initial
    }
```

View this live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/ur5mod8v/)